# Определенное число вводимых символов в inputmask

Tags: jquery

Необходимо задать в поле для ввода url префикс http:// и количество например 40 символов.
При вводе в инпут должно быть так [http://какаятоссылка.рф/тутчтотоещё/](http://%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84/%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91/)

```js
$('#mask').inputmask({mask: 'https://*{40}'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="mask" id="mask">
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Все уточнения стоит давать прямо в вопросе, кнопка "править" ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>


<input name="mask" id="mask" type="text">

<script>
jQuery('#mask').inputmask({
  mask: 'https://*{40}',
  digitsOptional: false,
  placeholder: '',
  allowMinus: true,
  clearMaskOnLostFocus: false,
  positionCaretOnClick: 'none',
  autoUnmask: true,
  definitions: {
            '*': {
                validator: "[0-9A-Za-z/.]",
                cardinality: 1,
                casing: "lower"
            }
        }
});
</script>
```

И посмотрите на странице документации, что это за опции "digitsOptional", "placeholder" и др. и нужны ли они вам вообще.

Comment: Такой вариант работает `$('#mask').inputmask({mask: 'https://*{40}'});` но точки и косые не вводятся.

Comment: Добавил переопределение валидатора: definition.

Comment: русские символы не вводятся))

Comment: Сделал так `[0-9а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z/.]` 
@Eleferen спасибо.